# Android - is there an accurate timer or sleep function?

Tags: android, multithreading, timer

When my app in the middle of a physical simulation I want it to run at a constant FPS (e.g. 30), as that affects the physics in a way. However, counting the time it took to end the current "frame" and calling Thread.sleep(1000/FPS - time already spent) is a bad idea since the OS scheduling can give a pretty high error/inaccuracy in the FPS.
Another bad idea is to have the simulation not sleep at all but simply running while(!time_has_come) time += System.nanotime(), because it will waste CPU resources and battery. Is there a more accurate and not resource-expensive way to create a timer
that will give pulse to my simulation in a constant FPS?

Comment: How accurate are we talking here? 30.0000 +/- 0.0001 fps?  30 +/- 1?

Comment: An error should be at most 0.01 seconds. I don't ask for much. I haven't measured yet but by looking at it I think any solution will be better than the current Thread.sleep method. Since its visible, the error of thread.sleep is around 0.1 seconds or more.

Comment: What timers are usually used for android games?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how accurate it is but the `scheduleAtFixedRate` method of the `Timer` class should do what you need.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29